# Appear To Have Cinnamon Backgrounds In Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: desktop-background

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed. As a newbie, I followed instructions to load the Cinnamon and Gnome desktops for comparison purposes. After comparing, I decided I prefer the default Ubuntu desktop.
My problem is, when I want to change my wallpaper now, I ALWAYS get the Cinnamon dialog box, not Ubuntu's. I have verified that I am choosing Ubuntu @ login, but I no Ubuntu options.
Should I just un-install Cinnamon & Gnome?

Comment: Do you have the apple key or a key with a diamond on it?

Comment: No, I don't. This is a Dell laptop that came pre-loaded with Windows 7. I am dual-booting to Ubuntu

Comment: I don't know how to mark this 'solved', but I just un-installed Cinnamon and the issue went away. Cinnamon is no longer among my login options.

Comment: I added the answer. Please accept it. Note to others: It is indeed CW.

Answer (score 0):

As per this comment:

> ... I just un-installed Cinnamon and the issue went away. Cinnamon is no longer among my login options. – ChunkyDrew 41 mins ago

one should uninstall `cinnamon-desktop`.